# How to take the control back from context manager in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question on how to take the control of context manager:

```
class cast:

    def __init__(self, enabled: bool = True, dtype) -> None:
        self.prev = False
        self.enabled = enabled
        self.dtype = dtype

    def __enter__(self) -> None:
        self.prev = is_cast_enabled()
        set_cast_enabled(self.enabled)
        set_cast_dtype(self.dtype)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type: Any, exc_value: Any, traceback: Any) -> None:
        set_cast_enabled(self.prev)
```

User can call the APIs to cast a region of code to a specific data type,

```
with cast(dtype=numpy.float16):
     c = a + b
```

with this context manager, `self.enabled=True` and the cast is done. For example, here if both a and b are in float32, the output will be float16 since the cast is done.

However I wanted to take the control back. So when user use this context manager, the cast won't take effect.
I am trying to achieve that the output c are still in float32 even with the context manager. How to do that?

I am trying to learn how to disable a decorator or context manager.

Comment: You can e. g. try to replace `cast` with a dummy context manager (before the manager is used).